# Using CMAKE_AUTORCC always rebuild rcc file and thus always links project

Tags: qt, cmake

With cmake 3.5.0 (on windows) and [CMAKE_AUTORCC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/prop_tgt/AUTORCC.html) and one rcc.qrc file in add_executable every build (using ninja) compiles the rcc file and links again even if there is nothing changed. Is that normal or is there something missing in my cmakelists.txt file?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(auto_moc_uic_rcc)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  main.cpp
  MainWindow
  MainWindow.ui
  rcc.qrc
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

If I remove CMAKE_AUTORCC and replace it with `qt5_add_resources(RCC rcc.qrc)` and add `${RCC}` to the executable, the project only builds and links if there is actually something changed.

Output of cmake (from cmake_gui):

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
Check for working C compiler using: Ninja
Check for working C compiler using: Ninja -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Ninja
Check for working CXX compiler using: Ninja -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done
```

First run `ninja -v`:

```
[1/7] cmd.exe /C "cd /D E:\source\builds\qt\debug\Test\junk\auto_moc_uic_rcc\auto_moc_uic_rcc && E:\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen E:/source/builds/qt/debug/Test/junk/auto_moc_uic_rcc/auto_moc_uic_rcc/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.dir/ Debug"
Generating ui_MainWindow.h
Generating moc_MainWindow.cpp
[2/7] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++ -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -c CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp
[3/7] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++ -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj -c E:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc/MainWindow.cpp
[4/7] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++ -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/main.cpp.obj -c E:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc/main.cpp
[5/7] cmd.exe /c
[6/7] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++ -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp.obj -c auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp
[7/7] cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe  -g   CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj  -o auto_moc_uic_rcc.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libauto_moc_uic_rcc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Widgetsd.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Guid.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Cored.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
```

Second run `ninja -v`. Consecutive runs have the same output:

```
[1/3] cmd.exe /C "cd /D E:\source\builds\qt\debug\Test\junk\auto_moc_uic_rcc\auto_moc_uic_rcc && E:\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen E:/source/builds/qt/debug/Test/junk/auto_moc_uic_rcc/auto_moc_uic_rcc/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.dir/ Debug"
[2/3] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic-rcc -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++ -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -c CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp
[3/3] cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\Qt\mingw\bin\c++.exe  -g   CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/auto_moc_uic_rcc_automoc.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj  -o auto_moc_uic_rcc.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libauto_moc_uic_rcc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Widgetsd.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Guid.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Cored.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
```

Here is the output of `ninja -v` when I use `qt5_add_resources(RCC rcc.qrc)` instead of CMAKE_AUTORCC:

```
[1/8] cmd.exe /C "cd /D E:\source\builds\qt\debug\Test\junk\auto_moc_uic_rcc\auto_moc_uic && E:\bin\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen E:/source/builds/qt/debug/Test/junk/auto_moc_uic_rcc/auto_moc_uic/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_automoc.dir/ """
Generating ui_MainWindow.h
Generating moc_MainWindow.cpp
[2/8] cmd.exe /C "cd /D E:\source\builds\qt\debug\Test\junk\auto_moc_uic_rcc\auto_moc_uic && E:\Qt\qt\bin\rcc.exe -name rcc -o E:/source/builds/qt/debug/Test/junk/auto_moc_uic_rcc/auto_moc_uic/qrc_rcc.cpp E:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic/rcc.qrc"
[3/8] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\g++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++  -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj -c E:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic/MainWindow.cpp
[4/8] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\g++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++  -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj -c qrc_rcc.cpp
[5/8] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\g++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++  -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/main.cpp.obj -c E:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic/main.cpp
[6/8] cmd.exe /c
[7/8] E:\Qt\mingw\bin\g++.exe   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IE:/source/src/Test/junk/autouic/auto_moc_uic -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtWidgets -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtGui -isystem E:/Qt/qt/include/QtCore -isystem E:/Qt/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++  -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/auto_moc_uic_automoc.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/auto_moc_uic_automoc.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/auto_moc_uic_automoc.cpp.obj -c auto_moc_uic_automoc.cpp
[8/8] cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\Qt\mingw\bin\g++.exe     CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/MainWindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic.dir/auto_moc_uic_automoc.cpp.obj  -o auto_moc_uic.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libauto_moc_uic.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.a E:/Qt/qt/lib/libQt5Core.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
```

And consecutive runs:

```
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D E:\source\builds\qt\debug\Test\junk\auto_moc_uic_rcc\auto_moc_uic && E:\bin\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen E:/source/builds/qt/debug/Test/junk/auto_moc_uic_rcc/auto_moc_uic/CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_automoc.dir/ """
```

Comment: From a clean build folder, can you show the output of the cmake configuration and of 2 or 3 consecutive builds with `ninja -v`?

Comment: @Antonio: I've added the output to my question.

Comment: Looking at "2/8", it seems that in the second case there's an auto-generated qrc_rcc.cpp, non auto-generated in the first case. It's indeed the file recompiled at every run in the first case. What happens, in the first case, if you remove `CMakeFiles/auto_moc_uic_rcc.dir/qrc_rcc.cpp`? (I wonder if it is a remainder of some other builds, which blocks cmake from generating it)

Comment: Removing `qrc_rcc.cpp` from the first case doesn't make a change. The file `qrc_rcc.cpp` is rebuild everytime over. I think "2/3" and "2/7" are creating that file in the first case and that "4/8" is creating that file in the second case. The difference is in the first case it uses c++ in the second case g++ and the output directory is different.

Comment: Also in the second case (using qt5_add_resources) `rcc.exe` is invoked explicitly.

Comment: In the second case, the file is definitely created at step 2/8 (check `-o` option). The lines you are point to build qrc_rcc.cpp.obj. It's not clear to me at which point in the first case qrc_rcc.cpp is generated. It seems at cmake configuration time; but then, why does it recompile if the file is not changed? Strange...

Comment: This might be because of cmake bug 0016049: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=16049